# Why is AngularJS removing part of my URL from the search bar

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am attempting to set up a state provider for a CRUD site.

When I go to `www.mysite.com/posts/mypost` the URL gets truncated down to `www.mysite.com/mypost` and it does not trigger the controller. This error does not persist when I use AngularJS' routeProvider, but the default provider is not robust enough for what I am trying to do. I assume that something truncates the URL before the stateProvider decides what to do next but I have no idea what is causing it. How can I stop the stateProvider(or whatever is the culprit) from truncating?

The following is a portion of the code.

```
$stateProvider.state('posts',{
  url: '/posts',
  templateUrl: localized.partials + '/post-list.html',
  controller: 'loopController'
}).state('post',{
  url: '/posts/:post/',
  templateUrl: localized.partials + "/post-single.html",
  controller: 'singlePostController'
}).state('pages',{
  url: '/pages',
  templateUrl: localized.partials + '/page-list.html',
  controller: 'pagesController'
}).state('page',{
  url: '/pages/:page',
  templateUrl: localized.partials + '/page-single.html',
  controller: 'singlePageController'
});


app.controller('singlePostController', 
['$scope', '$stateParams', 'Post', function ($scope, $stateParams, Post) 
{
  $http.get(resturl +'/posts/'+$stateParams.post).
    success(function(s){
      console.log(s);}).
    error(function(e){
      console.log(e)});
}
]);
```

Comment: I suppose you're not showing all of the relevant code. And probably you should have an eye on trailing slashes.

Comment: @hgoebl I have another provider for pages with the same issue. I'll attach that. Other than that everything is wrapped in an app.config. I cut out the trailing slash for the post but it still has the same behavior as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The trailing slash on your `post` state is what is causing your grief. To activate that state directly, you'll need to follow the pattern you defined - including the trailing slash. This would look like...

> www.mysite.com/posts/mypost/

You have some options to solve this. You can either remove the trailing slash from your state definition as such...

```
}).state('post',{
    url: '/posts/:post'
    ...
```

Or implement the following logic as suggested on the ui-router FAQ page for dealing with this

[How to: Make a trailing slash optional for all routes](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-make-a-trailing-slash-optional-for-all-routes)

This essentially drives some additional configuration as seen below

```
$urlMatcherFactoryProvider.strictMode(false);

$urlRouterProvider.rule(function ($injector, $location) {
    var path = $location.url();

    // check to see if the path already has a slash where it should be
    if (path[path.length - 1] === '/' || path.indexOf('/?') > -1) {
        return;
    }

    if (path.indexOf('?') > -1) {
        return path.replace('?', '/?');
    }

    return path + '/';
});
```

---

> Note: All routes in app/scripts/app.js must be redefined with trailing
>   /. This means that routes such as /things/:id become /things/:id/ as
>   well

Comment: Same error continued to occur. Determined that it was a server setting. +1 to this for validity though